# Preventing rounding to 2 decimal places

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have been working on some code for quite a few  days now and to be honest, I haven't got much hair left... I have searched everywhere including stackoverflow and I can't seem to anything matching my predicament.

I am using python 2.7.6 on Mint 17.3.
I need to work with date/time to at least millisecond precision. Working with date and time in whole seconds is fairly trivial but when you throw in milli or microseconds it becomes a completely different ballgame. Ultimately, I need to iterate through a log file and based upon certain conditions, I will need to find the difference between date/times of two lines to at least millisecond precision. The precision really does matter where a server, PLC's and scanners are involved in this warehouse conveyor situation. The log file date/time is formatted like this:

```
12-Apr-2016 23:59:59.720321
```

I thought the easiest way to deal with this was to convert the string into a timestamp and then add the microseconds afterwards. I am also not too sure of my use of strptime in this context as I know that timetuple() strips any fraction anyway, thus is surplus to requirements.

Anyway, after many, many tries, and days my code for this so far is below:

```
def timestampthen(timestring):
    tt = datetime.datetime.strptime(timestring, "%d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S.%f").timetuple()
    ut = float(calendar.timegm(tt))
    dotpos = timestring.rfind(".")
    frac = float(timestring[dotpos:])
    utfloat = float(ut + frac)
    return utfloat
```

In an example, ut = 
1460505599.0 and frac = 0.720321, yet utfloat = 1460505599.72

I know I can use format and %f but I am working with floats and not strings.
The above code works fine but why does the float come back with a 2 decimal point precision when it is 6 or more? I need more.
I would appreciate some guidance to point me in the right direction, please.

Comment: I run your code but `utfloat` for me is `1460505599.720321`. How can you say that your utfloat is rounded? with a print? what does `utfloat > 1460419273.37` returns?

Comment: Ok, I've changed the example to reflect the example log output

Comment: utfloat for me is rounded. Using my debugger it is rounded. This is the output I get inside of my IDE (Wing pro) or command line:- `1460419273.0 0.373317
1460419273.37
`

Comment: If you execute  `utfloat > 1460419273.72` do you get `True` or `False`?

Comment: @Francesco - I get True

Comment: So your float value is not rounded, otherwise you would have False (the two values would be equal). As pointed out by Raymond, probably you think it is rounded because by default, when you print it, the printed string is rounded to two decimals. Go on and use the value for your arithmetic!

Comment: @ Francesco - Thanks - much appreciated. I really don't know why python behaves like this as it is confusing and misleading. However I'll give it a whirl at see what happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The full precision is actually present, so there is no problem with the arithmetic.

The problem is that by default, `print` displays the rounded *str* of the variable instead of its full precision *repr*:

```
>>> ut = 1460505599.0; frac = 0.720321;
>>> ufloat = ut + frac
>>> print str(ufloat)
1460505599.72
>>> print repr(ufloat)
1460505599.720321
```

So, the solution to your problem is just to print the *repr* of the float value so it will display to full precision.   Hope this helps :-)

Comment: Hi, yes I can do that but as in my question, I need to work with high precision timings as floats and perform arithmetic, not print them out. str and repr just return strings. Why are the full float values hidden and how do I know that? I thought that they were being rounded, hence my confusion.

Comment: Thanks. I will go ahead and see what happens.